# Minimum Coin Change Leetcode problem (Dynamic Programming)

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Here's the question: https://leetcode.com/problems/coin-change/

I'm having some trouble understanding two different methods of dynamic programming used to solve this problem. I'm currently going through the *Grokking Dynamic Programming* course from educative.io, and their approach is to use subsets to search for each combination. They go about testing if a coin is viable, if so, then try it in the DFS. If not, skip the coin and go to the next index and try the next coin.

Here's Grokking's approach with memoization:

```
    def coinChange(self, coins: List[int], amount: int) -> int:
        def dfs(i, total, memo):
            key = (i, total)
            if key in memo:
                return memo[key]
            if total == 0:
                return 0
            if len(coins) == 0 or i >= len(coins):
                return inf
            
            count = inf
            if coins[i] <= total:
                res = dfs(i, total - coins[i], memo)
                if res != inf:
                    count = res + 1
                    
            memo[key] = min(count, dfs(i + 1, total, memo))
            return memo[key]
        return dfs(0, amount, {}) if dfs(0, amount, {}) != inf else -1
```

It doesn't do very well on Leetcode; it runs very slowly (but passes, nonetheless). The efficient algorithm that was in the discussions was this:

```
    def coinChange(self, coins: List[int], amount: int) -> int:
        @lru_cache(None)
        def dp(sum):
            if sum == 0: return 0
            if sum < 0: return float("inf")

            count = float('inf')
            for coin in coins:
                count = min(count, dp(sum - coin))

            return count + 1
        return dp(amount) if dp(amount) != float("inf") else -1
```

Does this second code have the same logic as "testing the subsets of coins?" What's the difference between the two? Is the for-loop a way of testing the different subsets, like with backtracking?

I tested the second algorithm with memoization in a dictionary, like the first, using `sum` as the key, and it tanked in efficiency. But then I tried using the @lru_cache with the first algorithm, and it didn't help.

Could anyone explain why the second algorithm is so much faster? Is it my memoization that sucks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this second code have the same logic as "testing the subsets of coins?"

If with subset you mean the subset of the coins that is still available for selection, then: no. The second algorithm does not reduce the problem in terms of *coins*; it reasons that at any time any coin can be selected, irrespective of previous selections. Although this may seem inefficient as it tries to take the same combinations in all possible permutations, this downside is minimised by the effect of memoization.

> What's the difference between the two?

- The first one takes coins in the order they are given, never going back to take an earlier coin once it has decided to go to the next one. So doing, it tries to reduce the problem in terms of available *coins*. The second one doesn't care about the order and looks at any permutation, it only reduces the problem in terms of *amount*.
- This first one has a larger memoization collection because the index is part of the key, whereas the second uses a memoization collection that is only keyed by the amount.
- The first one makes a recursive call even when no coin is selected (the one at the end of the inner function), since that fits in the logic of reducing the problem to fewer *coins*. The second one only makes a recursive call when the amount is further reduced.

> Is the for-loop a way of testing the different subsets, like with backtracking?

If with subset you mean that the problem is reduced to fewer coins, then no: the second algorithm doesn't attempt to apply that methodology.
The `for` loop is just a way to consider every coin. It doesn't reduce the problem size in terms of available *coins*, only in terms of remaining *amount*.

> Could anyone explain why the second algorithm is so much faster?

It is faster because the memoization key is smaller, leading to more hits, leading to fewer recursive calls. You can experiment with this and add global counters that count the number of executions of both inner functions (`dfs` and `dp`) and you'll see a dramatic difference there.

> Is it my memoization that sucks?

You could say that, but it is too harsh.

Comment: That was fantastic, thank you. That really cleared things up for me. I figured the key was too broad in my first memoization, but I never thought of using the clever trick to count their uses with a global variable. Genius!